# Update tags list asynchronously on question edit

Tags: feature-request, tags, live-refresh, inline-editor

Currently when you edit a question and change tags, the tags list to the right doesn't become synchronized. At least on SO using FF10.

So only page reload updates the list. Please fix that.

Comment: How do you know it's not updated? maybe another question removed this tag in the same time period...

Comment: @Nick: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I mean the list of tags by which a question is tagged, like http://i.imgur.com/gPfH71s.png. You edit a question, change tags, finish editing, page is being reloaded but the tag list to the right - isn't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the "tagged" list on the right has been removed many years ago.

Comment: @Sonuc: what's the purpose of closing 5 years old question?

Comment: @abatishchev We generally close unanswered questions that have to do with deprecated or removed features in order to remove them from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @Sonic: sure, make sense. Please close it.