# Editing tags doesnt change tagged

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update tags list asynchronously on question edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129518/update-tags-list-asynchronously-on-question-edit)

I noticed that if you click edit on a question and change the tag then press save, the tags below the question update but the tagged: in the top right corner do not update until you press the browser refresh button. Shouldn't those update with the post save as well?

Comment: They're cached. I actually consider this a feature when cleaning a tag since I have a handy link to the tag that was misused and can go back to that list with a single click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would presumably require a new fetching of related questions, as well. The overhead there might be unwieldy, since it's in the HTML delivered with the page, not as easy to change as the tags in the question.