# Tag counts don't reload on edited question

Tags: bug, tags, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update tags list asynchronously on question edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129518/update-tags-list-asynchronously-on-question-edit)

When a question is edited and you click on the little grey bar that says

> "this question has been edited - click here to reload"

the tags on the right side (under "Tagged", with tag counts) don't reload, even though the ones below the question do.